# switching between divs with jquery

Tags: php, ajax

suppose i have a list of users....

```
<a href="#">user1</a>
<a href="#">user2</a>
<a href="#">user3</a>
```

i want to switch div content related to the user while click on it and also want to align that div to the bottom right corner....i.e.

user1     user2       user3

how i should do that with jquery and $.ajax()

Comment: -1 This question needs more information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my understanding, you want to load user-content asynchrnously:

```
// attach this logic to the clicking of any link with class 'user'
$("a.user").click(function(e){
  // prevent default behavior of link
  e.preventDefault();
  // gather our username from the link
  var username = $(this).text();
  // fire off a POST, containing our username
  $.post("get-content.php", {user:username}, function(response){
    // set the HTML of <div id='content'></div> to whatever was received
    $("#content").html(response);
  // Indicates we're expecting HTML back
  }, "html");
});
```

-- Works with --

```
<a href="#" class="user">user1</a>
<a href="#" class="user">user2</a>
<a href="#" class="user">user3</a>
<div id="content">
  Load a users details
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to use Ajax. Just set up the 3 divs on the page and then use jQuery to hide/show.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("div.user_div").hide(); // hides all the user divs at first, so that if someone has JS disabled they'll still see the 3 divs without the hide/show effect

  $(".users a").click(function() {

     $("div.user_div").hide(); // hide all divs so that only one is showing at a time

     var myClass = $(this).attr("class"); // get class of the clicked link

     $("div."+myClass).show(); // show the div with the same class as the clicked link

  });

});

<div class="users">
  <a href="#" class="user1">user1</a>
  <a href="#" class="user2">user2</a>
  <a href="#" class="user3">user3</a>
</div>

<div class="user_div user1">
    ...content...
</div>
<div class="user_div user2">
    ...content...
</div>
<div class="user_div user3">
    ...content...
</div>
```

If you don't have a ton of divs to show/hide, Ajax is probably overkill.